# How to iteratively delete words defined in a list

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to delete from a .DOCX file all of the occurrences of unwanted words defined in a list. I'm creating a concordance but I don't want to process common words (e.g., "the"  "and"  "either" ...)

I have .DOCX file, which I've also stored as a .TXT, that is the main document from which I want to construct concordance. I have a list of unwanted words in a separate .TXT file.

How can I write (or record) a macro to repeatedly get the next word off the list, find and delete all occurrences of that word, repeat until list is exhausted.

It would be ok to use VBA in Word or create a macro in editor.exe (MS's free editor).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the text in the .TXT file you can use the Open ... For Input method.  You can loop through the words and lines in that .TXT file and do a Find/Replace in your doc.

Here is a code snip you can adapt:

```
Sub DeleteWordsStoredInTXTFileFromThisDoc()
Dim filePath As String
' change the filePath to point to your file
' you can put the full path, for example "C:\foldername\filename.txt"
filePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\textfile.txt"

Open filePath For Input As 1
Dim LineFromFile As String
Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, LineFromFile
    Dim LineItems() As String
    Dim LineItem As Variant
    ' depending on how you are listing your naughty words you need to pick from the following lines
    ' if your words are separated by commas
    'LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
    ' if your words are separated onto different lines
    LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, Chr(13))
    For Each LineItem In LineItems
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = LineItem
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Execute MatchWholeWord:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue
        End With
    Next LineItem
Loop
Close #1
End Sub
```

Please be aware that if your .TXT list of words to delete does not include a space either before or after the word then you will end up leaving behind an extra space in your doc.  Deleting the word "bad" from "Big bad wolf" will yield

```
"Big  wolf"
```

when you probably want

```
"Big wolf"
```

Adding spaces to your word list like "bad " or " bad" will help avoid this.  You have to proofread your document obviously.

Comment: Thanks Lucas! The VBA worked like a champ. I appreciate the help. --dave